# Is it possible to put custom message in win32 message queue in FIFO order?

Tags: winapi

There are few ways I can put a message for GUI thread.

**PostMessage**: according to docs, these messages are processed first (before most other messages). If I use this too often, the GUI thread may get stuck in processing only my messages and nothing else (will not respond to keyboard\mouse etc). This is too high-priority method.

**SetTimer**: WM_TIMER messages are processed last after everything else, so if there is any painting happening (like if I move a window continuously) all time will be spend for processing common messages and WM_TIMER will trigger too late.
This is too low-priority method.

I need something in-between to have my custom message processed ASAP but still leave room for the rest of messages to keep the GUI responsive.

What I'd like to try is to put some message to be processed just in same order as normal messages.
So here is the question, how can I do that?

---

Added:

I have one thread that prepares video frames and it needs to notify main (UI) thread that a new frame is ready and maybe display it. In a typical game loop it would be something like

- process messages until queue is empty
- process 1 frame
- repeat

But now I can't control message loop because it may be in modal popup or menu.

Comment: Same order as 'normal messages' is `PostMessage`. It would help if you did not only discuss possible solutions but tell us the problem/what you want to achieve.

Comment: There is no "in between".  Posted messages are processed in queue order.  If there is a risk that you call PostMessage() too often then you have a risk of your UI thread burning 100% core.  This must always be avoided.  Painting is also "low priority", so at least painting will seize.  You notice that.  Mouse/keyboard messages are not, other than WM_MOUSEMOVE.

Comment: Added description.
Maybe my understanding is wrong?

Here it says: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-peekmessagea


messages are processed in the following order:

Sent messages;  
Posted messages;  
Input (hardware) messages and system internal events;  
Sent messages (again);  
WM_PAINT messages;  
WM_TIMER messages;  


The fact is, as soon as I post messages slightly faster than they can be processed the UI gets stuck (not a single mouse message is handled).

Comment: For something like this, try using a [waitable event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/sync/event-objects) that you can signal when a frame is ready, and then change your message loop to use `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects()` to detect that signal while waiting for window messages.

Comment: I can't use MsgWaitForMultipleObjects() because even a popup menu has its own message loop.

Comment: If you have a different message loop going (modal dialog or menu for example) perhaps the video should pause anyway. An alternative is to use WM_ENTERIDLE which is received by the owner of a modal dialog or popup menu when the message loop is emptied. If you go that route you would check the new frame flag in WM_ENTERIDLE (in addition to wherever you do now) and invalidate the window when a new frame is indicated.

Comment: Thanks for WM_ENTERIDLE idea, didn't find it before. Yes I want the process to continue when menu or dialog is active. Think this is similar to how browser does not stop while you interact with menus.

Comment: Having made a production game engine from scratch many years ago our strategy was to combine a game oriented MsgWaitForMultiple objects style loop, and when a modal was up, supplement that with a ~10fps SetTimer based loop. So we'd render at ~120fps when the game was in the foreground, and at 10fps if there was a modal up - or the app was not foreground. If you really want high performance but screw the energy use then do a busy wait loop on QueryPerformanceCounter, doing a peek-message poll only while its not time to render the next frame (again with a WM_TIMER based fallback for modals)

Comment: Thanks, I think this is possible compromise (custom msg loop + WM_TIMER for fallback where my loop is not reachable).

Answer (score 0):

Assume the answer is "no" (no other way to insert message).
However, in processing posted message I can monitor time passed and immediately signal the same message through WM_TIMER instead of processing it.

update

After some observation it seems no given time (1 ms? 5 ms?) guarantees that input will be processed. What works instead is explicitly checking message queue for input messages:

```
case MY_MSG:
{
    MSG msg;
    if(PeekMessage(&msg,0,0,0,PM_NOREMOVE|PM_QS_INPUT))
        SetTimer(hwnd,MY_TIMER,0,0);
    else
        DoWork();
}
return 0;
```